# error in wordpress insert into custom table value empty or null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

i want to get title of all post from wordpress post and insert into a custom table but it always insert null value why

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
setup_postdata( $post ); 
insert_p_now(the_permalink());
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); 

function insert_p_now($a)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('wp_posttable', array('post_title' => $a), array('%s'));
}
?>
```

Comment: you want to store title or hyperlink in database ?

Answer (score 0):

In your function call you're not passing the post title as an argument.

```
insert_p_now(the_permalink());
```

It means that in your function

```
function insert_p_now($a)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('wp_posttable', array('post_title' => $a), array('%s'));
}
```

The value of `$a` is equal to `the_permalink()` which isn't your post_title of course.
If all you want to do is store the post title in a custom array, perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );
$allposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $allposts as $curpost ) : 
   $wpdb->insert('wp_posttable', array('post_title' => $curpost->post_title), array('%s')); 
endforeach;

?>
```

You can of course use a separate function if you'll be reusing the "insert into custom table" functionality.

Hope that helps!

Comment: still got blank records 
actually i want to create plugin ... so i want to copy all post from wordpress and insert into custom table .... don't know where are error

Comment: when i use 

$wpdb->insert('wp_employee', array('firstname' => 'ss', 'lastname' => 'ss'), array('%s', '%s'));

it working 

but when i place $title   got empty why ?

Comment: Hm, are you sure that the $title variable holds the title of the post? If you use get_posts(), the items in the result are objects. The title of those objects is stored in $varname->post_title where $varname is of course whatever you set it to!

Comment: yes when i print the title it is works fine ..but when i try to insert i got null ...

Comment: I see. What's the type of database field you're inserting into? VARCHAR?